# MacOS + iOS Safari unpredictably fail to play videos (HTML5 Video-Tag)

Tags: safari, html5-video, mobile-safari

I recently encountered a problem which happens in MacOS Safari (16.4) as well as Safari on iOS (16.4). I'm having difficulties even describing the problem as I don't understand it at all to be honest.

From time to time HTML5 video-tags are not playing anymore no matter what I try to do (reloading the page; clearing the cache; fully closing Safari and opening the page again). This includes videos with autoplay (+ muted, etc.) attributes as well as videos I have to start by clicking on them. I first noticed this behavior while working on a new website which utilizes a lot of video-tags (https://dev.bun.abh.eu/tags/animation/) and observing the console output. Funny thing is after trying to break other websites intentionally (reloading a lot of times; clearing cache; reloading again (no observable pattern)) I'm able to break videos on other webpages as well (e.g.: someform.studio, instagram.com)

The console output in Safari might give a hint at the underlying problem:

[image: Safari Console Output 01]
*Safari Console Output 01*

Safari first tries to fetch Bytes 0 – 1 and then requests the whole video file which fails.
I've read some threads about setting up the (video) server to return the right status code (206) but it already does. Safari is still not able to fetch the videos from time to time.

[image: Safari Console Output 02 (working)]
*Safari Console Output 02 (working)*

[image: Safari Console Output 03 (failing)]
*Safari Console Output 03 (failing)*

Last but not least: Chrome and Firefox behave fine and everything is working as expected.

---

## Debugging

So far I tried to isolate the problem and moving away from a fully working website to just putting the video-tags on it's own. The problem still occurs but is a lot less likely to happen. I already tried different approaches to including the video file, which are:

**01**

```html
<video muted autoplay playsinline loop controls>
    <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**02**

```html
<video muted autoplay playsinline loop controls src="test.mp4"></video>
```

[image: Test Environment Console Output 01 (working)]
*Test Environment Console Output 01 (working)*

[image: Test Environment Console Output 02 (failing)]
*Test Environment Console Output 02 (failing)*

**Test Environment**

https://dev.abh.eu/html5videotest/

---

## Server Setup

The two mentioned sites (In development, as well as the test site) are both operating on the same server running `nginx/1.18.0` which I'm able to modify in anyway I want.

I moved the test environment to a server running `Apache/2.4.57` which is the clients webserver and which I cannot customize in anyway: The problem still occurs.

---

Am I the only one experiencing this bug or is there anyone else out there?

Thanks!